# CTRL-whatever and Shift-whatever require double tap

Tags: updates, keyboard

After the update yesterday (2/3), epiphany 3.8.10 and some OS updates, using Shift and CTRL require double tapping. For example, if I'm doing CTRL-C I have to type C twice. If I want to make a capital letter I have to type the letter twice as well.

This appears to only affect epiphany. So CTRL-C to copy from the browser into other apps doesn't work without tapping the C key twice - same with CTRL-V or X. From Chrome to other apps or within Chrome, no problem. This most likely has something to do with the update to 3.8.10 from 3.8.5.

Has anyone been affected by this? Whats the solution?

Comment: I did an update and I do not have this problem.  However, I have "single" tap turned off in the tweak.  (so it works like normal OS stuff does)

Comment: I experience this too, but only in Epiphany.

Comment: Carl, yes I am only experiencing it in epiphany. I've updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Bihikku, I know what you are referring to in Tweaks, but I'm pretty sure that only affects the pantheon-files. This not only affects things like copy past, but if I want to make a capital letter at the beginning of a sentence I have to tap the letter twice.

Comment: I have the same error in a new installation today. Laptop is running without any problems in another Linux os. Inxi -M output: Machine: System: Dell product: Latitude E4310 v: 0001 Mobo: Dell model: 0T6M8G v: A01 Bios: Dell v: A10 date: 05/09/2012 regards, Just

Comment: I entered a new bug in the gnome bug tracker https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778539

Comment: And here is the Elementary bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1661556

Comment: I've just installed loki and updated all packages. I can confirm that this bug is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was introduced in 3.18.10 and is fixed in 3.18.11 with [this commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/epiphany/commit/?h=gnome-3-18&id=0f67243b5bba89ee5fa6f762fcc267354e61a615). You can wait for the updated package to come down the pipeline or make the change yourself as I did:

- `% sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- `% sudo apt-get build-dep epiphany-browser`
- `% apt-get source epiphany-browser`
- `% cd epiphany-browser-3.18.10`
- Make the changes from the commit I linked to: edit src/ephy-window.c, make a new line after line 882 and put the code `return TRUE;`
- `% dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`
- `% cd ..`
- `% sudo dpkg -i epiphany-browser*.deb`
- `% sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: So the question to the elementary team is wtf wasn't .10 skipped? lol Thanks for the post. I'll build .11 myself, much appreciated!

Comment: Lol, yeah, and same question to the Ubuntu team!

Comment: I get this error trying to build:    dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)

Comment: Can you try: `sudo apt-get build-dep epiphany-browser` before `dpkg-buildpackage`?

Comment: that allowed me to compile and it created the .deb files, but now i'm getting this error running the last command: dpkg: error processing package epiphany-browser (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Great! Now you should be able to fix things with `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53587/discussion-between-brad-pitcher-and-pretzel-jones).

Comment: Yep, did that and it worked! Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: @PretzelJones Great! I updated the answer

Comment: @PretzelJones Don't forget to mark it the correct answer :-)