# Keyboard behavior in Epiphany forms (Web version 3.18.10)

Tags: keyboard, epiphany

I noticed this strange behavior when I'm typing into text forms in the Epiphany browser (version 3.18.10 on eOS Loki):

when I have to perform combinations of keys (e.g. uppercase letters, special symbols, copy and paste commands) I have to press the key *twice* before I get the actual character or command done.

This does not occur in any other application I tried so far.

Any hint? Thank you!

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/ctrl-whatever-and-shift-whatever-require-double-tap